# How to automate "Windows Welcome" with unattended installation

Tags: windows-10, automation, unattended

I'm successfully automating my Windows 10 installation using an unattend.xml file. Everything runs and installs without a single user prompt.

My image contains multiple scheduled tasks, some of them are configured to run on system startup, and some of them have time intervals.

The problem is that none of my scheduled tasks run until I manually login with a user account for the first time. When logging in the screen "Hi, we're getting everything ready for you..." or something along those lines appears (you know: the black screen with white text).

Is there a way to automate this last step too? My installation must be fully autonomous.

Searching google didn't help, unfortunately.
All hints in the right direction are highly welcome.

Comment: Which account are these tasks set to work under?

Comment: @harrymc tasks are set to run as SYSTEM

Comment: Do by any chance the definitions of the tasks include the old computer name in their setup? Are the task commands included in [SetupComplete.cmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766314%28v=ws.10%29) or where?

Comment: @harrymc no they do not include any computer name. The startup task is calling a cmd script (which I created) called AtStartup.cmd this cmd is used to call further scripts (so I can add new scripts without reconfiguring task scheduler). AtStartup.cmd is run immediately after I log in for the first time. I'm not using SetupComplete.cmd as I need these scripts to run at every startup. I will add my task configuration as soon as I'm at my PC again.